# Create and import a big amount of data into a SQLite database from Java efficiently

Tags: java, sqlite

In one process, in server side with Java, I've to create a SQLite database and import a big amount of data (1.200.000 rows divided in 3 tables) and let the user download the generated database.

- My first approach was to create the SQLite database in memory, execute all the inserts and finally save the database to disk. It works, but it is really slow. It takes up to 42 seconds.
- The first improvement was to define one transaction. If I don't define the transaction, SQLite creates one for each insert, and this is slow. Doing only one transaction for all of them, it takes around 30 seconds. This is not enough for our case.
- A third approach, was to do the same but instead of executing each insert one by one calling executeUpdate, create a StringBuffer with all the inserts and send them all together using only one call to executeUpdate. This is slightly faster, but only 2 or 3 seconds.

When I though that there wasn't any way to do it faster, I realized that with the sqlite command line tool, I can execute ".import csv_file tablename" and it imports the data much faster, so I can export my data to CSV files and then import them with that tool. However, I would prefer to do not have to call any command line tool from the Java code but I've not found any way to execute the same import using the JDBC driver. So my questions are:

- Do you know any way to do the same CSV import that the command line tool does from Java code?
- Do you have a better approach to create a SQLite database and import a big amount of data in an efficient way?

**EDIT: The code & SQLite schema:**

I can't show the full schema definition but there are 3 tables created as follows:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE xxxxx USING rtree(...) with 5 attributes.
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE xxxxx USING fts3 (...) with 1 attribute.
CREATE TABLE poidata(xxxxx) with 15 attributes.
```

There isn't any foreign key between the tables and there isn't any index apart than the PKs.

Regarding the code, it is simple. I generate all the inserts in a StringBuffer and finally I execute:

```
Statement st = this.getConnection().createStatement();
st.execute("begin transaction");
st.executeUpdate(sql.toString());
st.execute("end transaction");
st.executeUpdate("backup to " + destination.getAbsolutePath());
```

I'm currently using the Xerial SQLite JDBC driver.

Comment: 1. Show your Java code. 2. Show your SQLite schema.

Comment: mmm... sometimes I don't understand some stackoverflow contributors... why this question has down votes? I would like to know the reason to improve it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why this has down votes either

Comment: Use one prepared statement for inserting a row into each table.

Comment: @Cl, yes, this was the first approach. The first idea was to use prepared statments and do the inserts with it. Using only one transaction for all of them, it takes around 30 seconds. Using only one executeUpdate with all the inserts in one call, takes more or less the same.

Comment: Sorry, I've checked it again and I was not using PreparedStatement for one query. The process now takes 25 seconds, it has improved around 5 seconds. My goal is that it should take < 15 seconds.

Comment: If you're not showing the full schema, then tell us if you have any other indices. Can you also show your SQL insert statements?

Comment: There isn't any index apart than the default ones for the primary keys. The inserts are simple inserts passing all the values. There are 3 tables so I do 3 inserts: insert into xxx(aaa,bbb,ccc...) values (aaa,bbb,ccc). All the data types are text, real or integer.

Comment: I understood this much. But do you currently issue 1,200,000 insert statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some optimizations, now it takes around 15 seconds to generate the database. After all the research and tests, the most important thigs are:

- Use only one transaction for all the inserts, and the transaction has to be declared explicitally. If it is not declared, by default it creates one new transaction for each insert.
- Create one and only one PreparedStatement to do all the inserts and reuse it as much as possible.

Comment: you are right, It has dramatically increased the speed.